# pythonic way of computing a value to a class object only once

Tags: python, class-method

I have a class where I need access to a computed value that can only be calculated per subclass.
This computation is not cheap, and since there are many instantiations of the subclasses, I want to compute this value only once per subclass.

I can think of two solution which I don't really like:

Either the parent class will have a `@classmethod` `start()` which will compute the values.
this enforces me to identify the precise location of the first instantiation of each class, so I've ruled this option out.

or, this code:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def _set_cls_attribute(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, 'big_attr'):
            return
        cls.big_attr = heavy_func(cls.VAL)

    def __init__(self):
        self._set_cls_attribute()

class B(A):
        VAL = 'b'

class C(A):
        VAL = 'c'


for _ in range(large_number):
        b = B()
        c = C()
```

I don't like using `hasattr` though...
Is there anything better?

Comment: metaclasses to the rescue?

Comment: Your latter looks fine. `hasattr` is OK.

Comment: your code is fine. I would skip the hasattr and try to catch AttributeError instead, that is the more pythonic way. “Easier to ask forgiveness than permission” http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092992/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metaclass is a handy way to solve this

```
class A_meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args):
        type.__init__(cls, *args)
        if hasattr(cls, 'VAL'):
            cls.big_attr = heavy_func(cls.VAL)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = A_meta

class B(A):
        VAL = 'b'

class C(A):
        VAL = 'c'
```

Another way along the same lines as yours. This has the advantage of deferring the call to heavy_func until the attribute is first accessed.

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'big_attr':
            self.__class__.big_attr = heavy_func(self.VAL)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without metaclasses or hasattr :

```
class A(object):
   @classmethod
   def attribute(cls):
       v = heavy_func(cls.VAL)
       cls.attribute = lambda k : v
       return v
```